# Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to convert a oracle code to snowflake,

In Oracle:

```
MIN(salary) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY commission_pct) "Worst",
```

What would be corresponding thing  as We dont have "keep" in oracle

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake doesn't have an equivalent "first" aggregation function.  One method is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select min(case when seqnum = 1 then salary end) as worst
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ? order by commission_pct) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by . . .
```

The `?` is for the columns used for the aggregation

Comment: You could also use the `QUALIFY` feature of Snowflake instead of using a sub-select.

Comment: @MikeWalton . . . The overall query is clearly an aggregation query and there might be a lot of other stuff going on.  I specifically did not use `qualify` for that reason.

Comment: @MikeWalton Can you use QUALIFY and rewrite the nested query please?

Answer (score 1):

so using this CTE for the example data:

```
WITH data AS (  
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('a', 2300, 10.1), 
        ('a',4000, 28.7), 
        ('b', 3000, 90.0) 
    AS v(dept, salary, commission_pct)  
)
```

And applying Gordon's code:

```
SELECT dept
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN salary end) AS worst
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY commission_pct) AS seqnum
      FROM data AS t
) 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

We get the first item from each department (dept) based on commission_pct, and then we take the MIN of those values.

```
2300
```

If we remove the Min and thus have

```
WITH data AS (  
    SELECT * FROM values 
        ('a', 2300, 10.1), 
        ('a',4000, 28.7), 
        ('b', 3000, 90.0) 
    AS v(dept, salary, commission_pct)  
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN salary END AS worst
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY commission_pct) as seqnum
      FROM data AS t
) ;
```

we get

```
WORST
2300
NULL
3000
```

So the difference is in the QUALIFY case, the non-first rows are not actually returned. Thus are not accessible for other opperations.

```
WITH data AS (  
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('a', 2300, 10.1), 
        ('a',4000, 28.7), 
        ('b', 3000, 90.0) 
    AS v(dept, salary, commission_pct)  
)
SELECT 
    salary AS worst
FROM data 
QUALIFY rOW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY commission_pct) = 1
;
```

just gives:

```
WORST
2300
3000
```

But Snowflake does have FIRST_VALUE, thus the effect of the KEEP

```
WITH data AS (  
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('a', 2300, 10.1), 
        ('a',4000, 28.7), 
        ('b', 3000, 90.0) 
    AS v(dept, salary, commission_pct)  
)
SELECT t.*
    ,first_value(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY commission_pct) as same_as_keep
FROM data AS t
;
```

giving:

```
DEPT    SALARY    COMMISSION_PCT  SAME_AS_KEEP
a       2300      10.1            2300
a       4000      28.7            2300
b       3000      90.0            3000
```

thus you (with some a sub-select required to disambiuate the double WINDOW functions)

```
WITH data AS (  
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('a', 2300, 10.1), 
        ('a',4000, 28.7), 
        ('b', 3000, 90.0) 
    AS v(dept, salary, commission_pct)  
)
SELECT q.*,
    min(same_as_keep) over (partition by true) as worst
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,first_value(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY commission_pct) as same_as_keep
    FROM data AS t
  ) AS q
;
```

giving:

```
DEPT    SALARY    COMMISSION_PCT    SAME_AS_KEEP    WORST
a       2300      10.1              2300            2300
a       4000      28.7              2300            2300
b       3000      90.0              3000            2300
```

But like a lot of things it all depends how you are using KEEP to what asspect of it's behavour you are wanting.

For example I do not know if if you swap MIN for COUNT if KEEP for this example data would give you 2 which is like Gordon's CASE version or if it gives you 3 which mean it behaves like FIRST VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use an aggregate function without creating subqueries/resorting to windowed funtions.

The idea is to use aggregate function that supports sorting like [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) and access first element:

```
SELECT sth,
     MIN(salary) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY commission_pct) "Worst"
FROM tab
GROUP BY sth;
```

Would be:

```
SELECT sth,
    (ARRAY_AGG(salary) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY commission_pct DESC, salary))[0]
FROM tab
GROUP BY sth;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the result using [MIN_BY/MAX_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by.html):

> Finds the row(s) containing the minimum or maximum value for a column and returns the value of another column in that row.

```
MIN(salary) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY commission_pct) AS Worst
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
MIN_BY(salary, commission_pct)
```