# How to combine data from different variables together in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition

Let's say I have data like this:

```
USER_ID                 TIMESTAMP   data  data2
   0001   2021-05-09 12:13:03.445            44
   0001   2021-05-09 13:13:03.445    rob    
   0001   2021-05-09 11:13:03.445       
   0002   2021-05-09 09:13:03.445  perry    333
   0002   2021-05-09 12:13:03.445   carl    333
   0003   2021-05-09 16:13:03.445  mitch      1
   0003   2021-05-09 17:13:03.445
   0002   2021-05-09 16:13:03.445  mitch      5
```

All I want to do is collect the most recent non-null value from each column and condense them into a table with each row being an entry.

Final result:

```
USER_ID   data  data2
   0001    rob     44 
   0003  mitch      1
   0002  mitch      5
```

Here's what I have but it's not complete:

```
WITH form AS (
    select b.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by user_id
            order by timestamp DESC
        ) as num
    FROM b
SELECT *
FROM b
WHERE num = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125612/equivalent-for-keep-in-snowflake/67236073#67236073):

It could be achieved with:

```
WITH cte(user_id, timestamp, "data", data2) AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES ('0001','2021-05-09 12:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,44),
   ('0001','2021-05-09 13:13:03.445'::timestamp,'rob',NULL),
   ('0001','2021-05-09 11:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,NULL),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 09:13:03.445'::timestamp,'perry',333),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 12:13:03.445'::timestamp,'carl',333),
   ('0003','2021-05-09 16:13:03.445'::timestamp,'mitch',1),
   ('0003','2021-05-09 17:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,NULL),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 16:13:03.445'::timestamp,'mitch',5)
  ) 
)
SELECT user_id,
  (ARRAY_AGG("data") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY timestamp DESC))[0]::STRING AS "data",
  (ARRAY_AGG(data2)  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY timestamp DESC))[0] AS data2
FROM cte
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| USER_ID |   data   | data2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
|    0001 | rob      |    44 |
|    0002 | mitch    |     5 |
|    0003 | mitch    |     1 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

`ARRAY_AGG` by default omits NULLs and it is sorted by timestamp descending. Once array per `user_id` is created it is a matter of accesing first element(element with index [0]).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . this is where `ignore null`s is really useful -- but Postgres doesn't support that (yet??).

Instead, you can use arrays ordering the non-NULL values first and then by timestamp:

```
select user_id,
       (array_agg(data order by (data is not null) desc, timestamp desc))[1],
       (array_agg(data2 order by (data2 is not null) desc, timestamp desc))[1]
from t
group by user_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e741eec1d4130e6ee980adebb6f632bf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: is or isnt useful

Comment: @JohnThomas . . . I knew what meant.  Now, I've rephrased it to communicate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IGNORE NULL using the `LAST_VALUE` or `FIRST_VALUE` function.  For your dataset:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('0001','2021-05-09 12:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,44),
   ('0001','2021-05-09 13:13:03.445'::timestamp,'rob',NULL),
   ('0001','2021-05-09 11:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,NULL),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 09:13:03.445'::timestamp,'perry',333),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 12:13:03.445'::timestamp,'carl',333),
   ('0003','2021-05-09 16:13:03.445'::timestamp,'mitch',1),
   ('0003','2021-05-09 17:13:03.445'::timestamp,NULL,NULL),
   ('0002','2021-05-09 16:13:03.445'::timestamp,'mitch',5)
  ) x (id, ts, data, data2)
)
```

You'd do something like this:

```
SELECT id,
       LAST_VALUE(data) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ts) as data_last,
       LAST_VALUE(data2) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ts) as data2_last
FROM x
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) = 1;
```