# snowflake-sql: case when min vs first_value windows function

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, min

I hope someone can help. Suppose I have this table

| sto_id | pro_id | o_date | d_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 111 | 2021-04-01 |  |
| 30 | 111 | 2021-04-10 | 2021-04-10 |
| 30 | 222 | 2021-04-15 |  |
| 30 | 222 | 2021-04-18 | 2021-04-19 |
| 30 | 333 | 2021-04-20 |  |

and the result I want to see is

| first_sto_id | pro_id | min_o_date | first_d_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 111 | 2021-04-01 |  |
| 30 | 222 | 2021-04-15 | 2021-04-19 |
| 30 | 333 | 2021-04-20 |  |

so if the sto_id is 30 and d_date is null I want so see the next d_date for this pro_id if available. And if sto_id is not 30 then d_date even if it is null.

I tried this:

```
select 
first_value(sto_id) OVER (PARTITION BY pro_id ORDER BY o_date ASC) as first_sto_id,
pro_id,
min(o_date) OVER (PARTITION BY pro_id ORDER BY o_date ASC) as min_o_date,
case when sto_id='30' then min(d_date) OVER (PARTITION BY pro_id ORDER BY o_date ASC)
else first_value(d_date) OVER (PARTITION BY pro_id ORDER BY o_date ASC) end as first_d_date
from tab1
```

but I am not getting the result I would need. Here also the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Np4AQ8RoaFmy6DMQHVKUX/0)

Any suggestions??
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using arrays:

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT
 (ARRAY_AGG(sto_id ORDER BY o_date))[1] AS first_sto_id
,pro_id
,MIN(o_date) AS min_o_date
,CASE WHEN (ARRAY_AGG(sto_id ORDER BY o_date))[1] != '30'
           THEN (ARRAY_AGG(d_date ORDER BY o_date))[1]
      ELSE (ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(d_date ORDER BY o_date),NULL))[1]
      END
FROM tab1
GROUP BY pro_id
ORDER BY pro_id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c872e5c360fb72e92bfb1c931363d67)**

Snowflake version:

```
SELECT
 (ARRAY_AGG(sto_id) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY o_date))[0]::int AS first_sto_id
,pro_id
,MIN(o_date) AS min_o_date
,CASE WHEN (ARRAY_AGG(sto_id) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY o_date))[0] != '30'
           THEN (ARRAY_AGG(d_date) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY o_date))[0]::date
      ELSE (ARRAY_COMPACT(ARRAY_AGG(d_date) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY o_date)))[0]::date
      END
FROM tab1
GROUP BY pro_id
ORDER BY pro_id;
```

Related: [Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236073/5070879)

Comment: Hi @Lukasz , I get the first_sto_id in this format "30" and the d_date also like this "2021-04-19". Can this be avoided?

Comment: @pooq Cast is required :: int/::date