# SQL - select only one value from multiple rows under certain condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi guys, I am trying to solve the problem since hours researching in the internet and couldn't find any solution.
I have a table like:

| Number | Language | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | D | German name for 1111 |
| 1111 | E | English name for 1111 |
| 1111 | S | Spanish name for 1111 |
| 2222 | D | German name for 2222 |
| 3333 | S | Spanish name for 3333 |

The logic should be, for each number:

- Return english name, if Language =  E is available.
- If E is not available, D is available, return German name.
- If E and D not available, return "name not available"

So the result table should like:

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | English name for 1111 |
| 2222 | German name for 2222 |
| 3333 | name not available |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
WITH cte(Number, LANGUAGE, Name) AS (
  SELECT 1111,    'D',    'German name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111,    'E',    'English name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111,    'S',    'Spanish name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222,    'D',    'German name for 2222' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333,    'S',    'Spanish name for 3333'
)
SELECT Number, 
    (ARRAY_AGG(IFF(LANGUAGE IN ('D','E'), NAME, 'name not available')) 
     WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DECODE(LANGUAGE,'E',0,'D',1,2)))[0]::TEXT AS name
FROM cte
GROUP BY Number
ORDER BY Number;
```

Output:

[image]

How does it work:

`IFF(LANGUAGE IN ('D','E'), NAME, 'name not available')` - allowing only 'D' and 'E'

`DECODE(LANGUAGE,'E',0,'D',1,2))` - sorting order, 'E' first, 'D' second

Related: [Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236073/5070879)

---

Alternatively using `QUALIFY`:

```
WITH cte(Number, LANGUAGE, Name) AS (
  SELECT 1111,    'D',    'German name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111,    'E',    'English name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111,    'S',    'Spanish name for 1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222,    'D',    'German name for 2222' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333,    'S',    'Spanish name for 3333'
)
SELECT Number, 
   CASE WHEN LANGUAGE IN ('E','D') THEN NAME ELSE 'name not available' END AS Name
FROM cte
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Number 
                          ORDER BY DECODE(LANGUAGE,'E',0,'D',1,2)) = 1
ORDER BY Number;
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz, this solved my problem perfectly! Thanks very much for your quick answer and the detailed explanation of the solution :)