# Use last_value() with group_by instead of as window function in Snowflake

Tags: group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use `last_value()` or any similar function in a `group by` query instead of as a window function. It it possible?

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (Group_id INT, Fecha DATE, Sales INT)
;

INSERT INTO test (Group_id,Fecha,Sales)
VALUES  ( 1, '2021-10-15', 100 ),
        ( 1, '2021-11-15', 90 ),
        ( 1, '2022-01-15', 95 ),
        ( 2, '2021-10-15', 50 ),
        ( 2, '2021-11-15', 60 ),
        ( 2, '2022-01-15', 70 )
;
```

Current solution:

```
 select 
      distinct 
      group_id,
      last_value(sales) over (partition by group_id order by fecha) as last_sales,
      max(sales) over (partition by group_id) as max_sales
  from test
```

Desired solution:

```
  select
      group_id, 
      max(sales) as max_sales,
      last_value(sales) over (order by fecha) as last_sales
  from test
  group by group_id
```

Is there any way I can use the last_value() function as in the desired solution?

Output should be:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to achieve similar effect using`ARRAY_AGG`:

```
SELECT Group_id,
      -- MAX_BY should be preferred way
      MAX_BY(sales, fecha) AS last_sales_,
      -- alternative
      (ARRAY_AGG(sales) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY fecha DESC))[0] AS last_sales,
      MAX(Sales) AS max_sales
FROM test
GROUP BY Group_id
ORDER BY Group_id;
```

Output:

[image]

Related: [Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125612/equivalent-for-keep-in-snowflake)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the real example this solution worked but it changed the type of the `sales` variable. I wrapped this exact function in `to_number()` function

Comment: @alvaropr   `::datatype` could be use too:   `(ARRAY_AGG(sales) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY fecha DESC))[0]::number AS last_sales,`

Comment: This has the downside of throwing this lovely obscure error message if your data is too big to fit. `Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 18390404`. SF partition size is 16mb.

Comment: @Josh To avoid this limitation `MIN_BY/MAX_BY` should be used (introduced after this answer was provided).

Comment: Yep! Actually ended up being the solution I used, lovely function :). Meant our SQL code was just 1 line!