# Select first match based on column rule

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem Statement:** need any first match based on hier rules column defined
Example: like no match for hier 1, but hier 2 is matched, then select sec_id for hier 2

**Sample:**

```
with cte_tab as (select column1 as hier, column2 as rule, column3 as sec_id from values
       (1, 'NO','COM'), (1, 'NO','COM'), (2, 'NO','COM'), (3, 'YES','COM')
    order by column1)
select * from cte_tab;
```

**Expected Output:**
From the example below, the expected output would be the row with hier = 3 as it's the first match from the group for which rule='YES'

Note: there could be multiple entries for the hier and returning all of them is a valid scenario if the rule = 'YES' is valid for that group.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QAULIFY` and `DENSE_RANK`:

```
with cte_tab as (
   select column1 as hier, column2 as rule, column3 as sec_id 
   from values
       (1, 'NO','COM'), (1, 'NO','COM'), (2, 'NO','COM'), (3, 'YES','COM')
   order by column1)
select * 
from cte_tab
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY RULE='YES' DESC, HIER) = 1;
```

This version returns only `YES` for HIER 3

Output:

[image]

---

If the goal is to get entire HIER 3 regardless of rule then:

```
with cte_tab as (
    select column1 as hier, column2 as rule, column3 as sec_id 
    from values
       (1, 'NO','COM'), (1, 'NO','COM'), (2, 'NO','COM'),
       (3, 'YES','COM'), (3, 'NO', 'A')
    order by column1)
select * 
from cte_tab
QUALIFY HIER=(ARRAY_AGG(HIER) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RULE='YES' DESC) OVER())[0]::TEXT
```

Output:

[image]

Related: [Equivalent for Keep in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236073/5070879)

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz Szozda. The second solution is what I was intending to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something but if you just need to filter your data for qualifying hiers, isn't this simpler?

```
select *
from t
where hier in (select min(hier) from t where rule='YES' )
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil Coulson.
This I suspect won't work if we have something like below `with cte_tab as (
   select column1 as hier, column2 as rule, column3 as sec_id 
   from values
       (1, 'NO','COM'), (1, 'YES','COM'), (2, 'NO','COM'), (2, 'NO','COM'), (3, 'YES','COM'),(3, 'NO','COM')
   order by column1)
select * from cte_tab`
as it would print both 1 and 3 but I was expecting to stop at the first match.

Comment: @Abhishek That's very easy to handle. See my update